# consider comma as a dot when calculate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Is there a way to consider a comma (,) as a dot (.) when input in a form using jQuery calculate functions?
I tried replace but I does not work

```
function calculate(e){
    var bredd2 = bredd.toString().replace(",", ".");
    var djup2 = djup.toString().replace(",", ".");

    $('#m2').val($('#bredd2').val() * $('#djup2').val());
    $('#totalpris').val($('#m2').val() * $('#m2pris').val());
}
```

Comment: You should parse your strings so that you do computations on numbers : `parseFloat(someString)`

Comment: What are `bredd` and `djup2` ? You don't seem to do the replacement on the right variables...

Comment: FYI, `replace` replaces only the first occurence of the provided string.

Comment: @Mr_Green In that case that's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a replacement on the wrong variables. Do

```
function calculate(e){
    var bredd2 = parseFloat($('#bredd2').val().replace(",", ".")),
        djup2 = parseFloat($('#djup2').val().replace(",", ".")),
        m2pris = parseFloat($('#m2pris').val().replace(",", ".")),
        m2 = bredd2 * djup2,
        totalpris = m2 * m2pris;

    $('#m2').val(m2);
    $('#totalpris').val(totalpris);
}
```

Of course you could create an utility function to ease that :

```
$.fn.parsedVal = function(){
   return parseFloat(this.val().replace(",", "."))
}

function calculate(e){
    var m2 = $('#bredd2').parsedVal() * $('#djup2').parsedVal(),
        totalpris = m2 * $('#m2pris').parsedVal();

    $('#m2').val(m2);
    $('#totalpris').val(totalpris);
}
```